# Number of helpful flags appearing different

Tags: bug, profile-page, flags, flag-history

The User Profile Page shows how much helpful flags a user has raised. Clicking on that number redirects to another page that shows the complete details of the flags, their number, helpful, declined, etc. The number of helpful flags shown there is not equal to the number I view on the Profile Page.

It's not the first time but I've noticed it many times before as well.

Is this happening only with me or anybody else has experienced it?

Comment: Please do not roll back edits made to your post unless they are particularly destructive. I made those edits for a reason.

Comment: Try learning from those edits so that you can apply those improvements on your future posts.

Comment: Not on the offensive, i rollback very small changes as this one.
If you let me know the 'a reason', i won't rollback for that reason in future.

Comment: There is no need for the bold formatting. The text can stand on its own and the point raised is clear enough. Title Case is not necessary for the title of your questions. The consensus is not in favor of those. And there were various mistakes in spelling. I would normally have edited even more drastically, but kept it fairly light.

Comment: @CodingMash: if you don't want "minor" edits on your posts, at least write I in uppercase.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. Your Point is valid.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bug afaik.

The total displayed is a sum of all the flags which were determined to be helpful. This includes moderator attention flags, spam flags, flags for offensive content and comment flags.

If you sum that total, this should be exactly the total amount displayed in your profile page. Perhaps there is a small caching delay between the two, but this won't differ by much.

Comment: You may be right. But i have asked this question after observing for about two weeks. Both the numbers almost always never match even if I do not flag another post in between.

Comment: If so, report the total number you see on your profile page and perhaps add a screenshot of the totals you see on the linked page.

Comment: Ok. I will shortly add them with the question.