# Different number of helpful flags in profile page and flagging history overview

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I wonder if it is possible to make the flagging history overview a little more understandable. I thought of asking "why are there differences?" but I found the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148711/number-of-helpful-flags-appearing-different).

I think my misunderstanding is in not understanding this overview:

[image: flagging history]

First, when you look at this, you think you had 147 helpful flags. But my profile page says something different:

[image: profile page]

It seems that the count of 159 is correct, since 147 + 5 + 1 + 6 = 159, but I can't read it in the overview.

Is it possible to clarify the total count in the overview?

Maybe by putting the "deemed helpful" at the bottom of the first group and making that one, and making the other "deemed helpful" bold or something, or add a headers and a summary at the bottom?